# Sorting data in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I have a `json` file containing an array with some objects called `json.bc` shown by `fetch()` request. I want to sort all the objects based on `total` field but the data will be sort in every page not all the pages.How can I sort them?

```
class App extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        data: [],
        library: null,
        perPage: 20,
        currentPage: 1,
        maxPage: null,
    }
}
componentDidMount() {
    fetch('/json.bc', {
        method: 'get',
    })
        .then(response => response.text())
        .then(text => {
            let Maindata = JSON.parse(text.replace(/\'/g, '"'))
            this.setState(state => ({
                ...state,
                data: Maindata
            }), () => {
                this.reorganiseLibrary()
            })
        }).catch(error => console.error(error))
}

reorganiseLibrary = () => {
    const { perPage, data } = this.state;
    let library = data;
    library = _.chunk(library, perPage);
    this.setState({
        library,
        currentPage: 1,
        maxPage: library.length === 0 ? 1 : library.length
    })
}
// Previous Page
previousPage = event => {
    this.handleClick(event)
    this.setState({
        currentPage: this.state.currentPage - 1
    })
}
// Next Page 
nextPage = event => {
    this.handleClick(event)
    this.setState({
        currentPage: this.state.currentPage + 1
    })
}

// handle per page
handlePerPage = (evt) =>
    this.setState({
        perPage: evt.target.value
    }, () => this.reorganiseLibrary());

// handle render of library
renderLibrary = () => {
    const { library, currentPage } = this.state;

    if (!library || (library && library.length === 0)) {
        return <div>NoResult</div>
    }
    return library[currentPage - 1].sort((a, b) => a.total - b.total).map((item, i) => (
        <div className="Item">
            {item.total}
        </div>
    ))
}

render() {
    const { library, currentPage, perPage, maxPage } = this.state;
    return (
        <div>
            {this.renderLibrary()}
            <ul id="page-numbers">
                <li className="nexprevPage">
                    {currentPage !== 1 && (
                        <button onClick={this.previousPage}><span className="fa-backward"></span></button>
                    )}
                </li>
                <li className="controlsPage activeCnt">{this.state.currentPage}</li>
                <li className="restControls">...</li>
                <li className="controlsPage">{this.state.maxPage}</li>
                <li className="nexprevPage">
                    {(currentPage < maxPage) && (
                        <button onClick={this.nextPage}><span className="fa-forward"></span></button>
                    )}
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    )
}}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('Result'))
```

Comment: Use this.state.data in your renderLibrary()  instead of library[currentPage - 1] could solve your problem? Use it and get only needed page from sorted data.

Comment: @G_S It could not solve my problem , the data is not shown in pagination.

Comment: If I am not understanding it wrong, data is in state of your component. You can use it in your component to perform the needed pagination.

Comment: Sorry but can you show what you mean in my code?

Comment: What is the problem you are facing. You are already sorting the data per page in `renderLibrary` function.

Answer (score 0):

The whole loaded data is saved in `this.state.data` (in `componentDidMount`).

`setState` callback calls then `this.reorganiseLibrary()` - this is the place where pagination occurs, result is stored in `this.state.library` and used for rendering.

To change sorting (whole set) you must sort data before pagination, in `this.reorganiseLibrary()`.

Steps needed:

- save sorting order in the state (like `perPage`);
- provide event handler for order change - remember to use `this.reorganiseLibrary()` in `setState` callback (like in `handlePerPage`);
- use ordering value for sorting in `this.reorganiseLibrary()` (before `library = _.chunk(library, perPage);`)
- remove `sort` parts from `renderLibrary()`

Thats all.