# How to correctly use a specific array value in react

Tags: reactjs

I am attempting to get API data to correctly display on a react-table. I
am able to get all data to display onto my localhost but some values are not needed. I am thinking that if I were to reference each array specifically, then it would work:

```
    {objStationD.[""0""].Origin}
```

The bracket value is what the console says is its property path.
I will post the array itself below as a reference point.

The following is my frontend code:

```
     {this.state.data.map(objStationD =>
      <Table dark>
       <thead>
         <tr>
           <th>Origin</th>
           <th>Due date</th>
           <th>Destination</th>
           <th>Due</th>
         </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody>
         <tr>
           <th scope="row">{objStationD.[""0""].Origin}</th>
           <td>{objStationD.Origintime}</td>
           <td>{objStationD.Destination}</td>
           <td>{objStationD.Duein}</td>
         </tr>
       </tbody>
     </Table>
   )};
```

This is a snippet of the array returned:

```
    Array(4)
    0:
    Destination: ["Sligo"]
    Origin: ["Dublin Connolly"]
    Destinationtime: ["14:15"]
    length: 1
    __proto__: Array(0)
   Origintime: ["11:00"]

   1: {Servertime: Array(1), Traincode: Array(1), Stationfullname: Array(1), Stationcode: Array(1), Querytime: Array(1), …}
   2: {Servertime: Array(1), Traincode: Array(1), Stationfullname: Array(1), Stationcode: Array(1), Querytime: Array(1), …}
   3: {Servertime: Array(1), Traincode: Array(1), Stationfullname: Array(1), Stationcode: Array(1), Querytime: Array(1), …}
    length: 4
    __proto__: Array(0)
```

Comment: where is `Origin` property in above array returned?

Comment: Have you tried just referencing it by index, something like `objStationD[0].Origin`?

Comment: @JamesWhiteley I have tried it but it returns an error saying "unexpected token."

Answer (score 1):

> I
>   am able to get all data to display onto my localhost but some values are not needed.

convert (strip and rename props if required) your data to desired format, f.e. using `Array.map` method, sth like:

```
const data = loadedData.map( obj => ({
       origin: obj.[""0""].Origin,
       time: obj.Origintime,
       destination: obj.Destination,
       dueIn:  obj.Duein
     })
)
```

Comment: thank you for your response. What I meant by "some values are not needed" is that I only need specific arrays, ie 4 arrays. When I try to display this onto my table it puts all values in, so maybe need to filter which ones are displaying.

Comment: filtering, sorting, pagination? maybe sth like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55980642/6124657) ?